# makefile to read another directory

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a c++ project. In my Project folder, I have three sub project folders.

```
Proj_Folder
   Sub_Proj1
       proj1.cpp
       makefile
   Sub_Proj2
      proj2.cpp
      makefile
   Sub_Proj3
      proj3.cpp
      makefile
ShareAll.cpp
```

My all sub projects uses the ShareAll.o file.
In Sub_Proj1, I have a makefile. That makefile need to look for ShareAll.o which is located in it's Parent Directory.
I tried the below code.

```
OBJS =  ShareAll.o proj1.o

proj1: ShareAll.o proj1.o
    ${CXX} ${CFLAGS} -o proj1 ${OBJS}

proj1.o : proj1.cpp
    ${CXX} ${CFLAGS} proj1.cpp

ShareAll.o : ../ShareAll.cpp
    ${CXX} ${CFLAGS} ../ShareAll.cpp
```

This makefile creates, **ShareAll.o** in the folder of Sub_Proj1.
But I don't want this. I just need to reference from the Parent Directory. It should not create a new **'.o'** file in a sub_proj folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So ... just use `../ShareAll.o` instead of `ShareAll.o`?

```
OBJS =  ../ShareAll.o proj1.o

proj1: ${OBJS}
        ${CXX} ${CFLAGS} -o $@ $+

proj1.o : proj1.cpp
        ${CXX} ${CFLAGS} -c $< -o $@

../ShareAll.o : ../ShareAll.cpp
        ${CXX} ${CFLAGS} -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: Thank you. Its working. I have a folder called "Include" in Proj_Folder. It contains all necessary *.h files. I need to add the Folder as dependency. It is only contains .h files. How can I do this in above program?